# Using Java WorldWind, but want an alternative

Tags: java, image, worldwind

So, I realize this might not be the right site, but I didn't think it would be respectful to ask it on the WorldWind forums. If it should be somewhere else, please let me know.

Anyways...

I have this Java application that currently uses WorldWind to display a globe and place bitmaps corresponding to an item's location. WorldWind was initially picked for the project as an alternative to Google's product and because it had the "3D" effect. However, requirements change, and the 3D Globe is no longer necessary. (Also, WorldWind was a little heavy for the project - we found out that we would really like just a 2 color version if possible.)

My question to you all is:

What would you suggest as an alternative to WorldWind? I'm looking for just a "flat" map (or even just an image of the world...) that is zoomable, and is possible to layer objects on top of it (and those objects can move over time).

I have not really done much with map/image programming so please take that into consideration when replying :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked out [GeoTools](http://www.geotools.org/)? I believe it should be more than capable for what you are trying to do, though like WorldWind, the actual *content* is what contributes to things like color and such. Check out the [quickstart](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/quickstart/index.html) which even includes some sample shapefile content, and has an example of an application which displays the shapefile content in a map frame. You may have to get your hands a bit dirty to play with geo-referenced bitmaps, though...

EDIT: I also found this on the Google: [JXMapViewer](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/10/30/building-maps-into-swing-app-with-jxmapviewer.html)

(just for the record, WorldWind has a "[FlatMap](http://builds.worldwind.arc.nasa.gov/worldwind-releases/1.2/docs/api/gov/nasa/worldwind/globes/EarthFlat.html)" option)